# React rendering properly but not reading correct state in function

Tags: reactjs

```
 useEffect(() => {
   getNotes()
  }, []);


const getNotes = async () => {
    const notes = await fetch(`${getNotesPath()}`);
    const notesData = await notes.json();
    setEstimateNotes([...notesData]);
  };

const createNote = async () => {
    console.log(estimateNotes); // gives empty string
    let noteParams = {
      ...  // this all works fine and note is created in db
    };

    const url = `${getNotesPath()}/create`;
    const body = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        ...noteParams,
      }),
    };

    const newNote = await fetch(url, body);
    const newNoteData = await newNote.json();
    setEstimateNotes([...estimateNotes, newNoteData]) // renders 1 note
  };

  const destroyNote = async (id) => {.  // works great!
    const destroyedNote = await fetch(`/api/notes/${id}/destroy`);
    const destroyedNoteData = await destroyedNote.json();
    setEstimateNotes(
      [...estimateNotes].filter((note) => note.id !== destroyedNoteData.id)
    );
  };

 return estimateNotes.map((note, i) => {
    return (
      <div key={`notes-${i}`} className="note">
           ... renders all my notes fine
      </div>
    );
  });
```

I'm having a very strange problem with React. For some reason my state seems to be working fine and everything renders properly but when I go to update it in my createNote function it's like it's completely disconnected. I console.log an empty array while I'm rendering all my notes from the same state. If I manipulate the state it just starts from the empty array instead of what I see. What is even stranger is that my destroy function works just fine.

I've never seen this before and can't find anything else about it on Stack Overflow. Usually the problem is going the other way (not rendering on state update)

Comment: Is newNoteData an array or an object?

Comment: @SiddharthSeth an object

Comment: Could you still try this in your createNote method --> [ ...estimateNotes, ...newNoteData ]?

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: newNoteData is not iterable @SiddharthSeth

Comment: Please share the entire code (except the Url) for the createNote method